# Order in which to take max and square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

> I am pretty sure that $(\displaystyle\max_i\{|a_i|\})^2=\max_i\{|a_i|^2\}$ where $i=1,\ldots, n$ and $a_i\in\mathbb{R^n}$. Could someone please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because $x \mapsto x^2$ is an increasing function for $x > 0$.

Comment: Does any increasing function commute with the operation of taking max?

Comment: Yes; try to show this, it's not too hard.

Comment: I will. Thank you very much.